# Use platform TPM as U2F for web applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, tpm, u2f, webauthn

**The Problem:**
Use the platform TMP of my `Windows` Laptop/PC (no external device or USB token) as U2F in a web application to check if it is a known device.

**My intended solution:**

- I need to store/create *something* (Cetificate, Private/Public Key or Virtual SmartCard) in the TPM that is known by the web application.
- If possible an external application stores/creates this something in the TPM on the device (no Registration process with the web application)
- The web application then silently checks if the device has that *something* without user interaction when the user tries to login

**Where I'm stuck:**

- I read [here](https://www.google.de) that `WebAuthn` might be able to use the TPM without user interaction, but I did not understand how

  - *"...in the case where there is no user verification at all, the TPM would be used as a U2F style second factor authenticator."*
- Can I only use the authenticators provided by the OS (Windows) or can I create a custom one that does not need a user interaction but still uses the TPM of the device?

**Questions:**

- Is my intended solution even possible?
- Is `WebAuthn` the right way to go or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Proving TPM based services is usually a task of the OS. Which OS and web browser do you use?

Comment: Windows with FireFox/Edge

Comment: Using Edge/Chrome you should be able to use Windows as Fido2 platform authenticator (check Windows Hello system settings). Already did that via https://webauthn.io. Set "Authenticator type" to "Platform (TPM)".

Comment: Yes this is possible, so i think the Problem was that i had not configured Windows Hello or something (I will edit my Question). But the problem i still have is how or if i can use the platform TMP as an U2F. Maybe i don't even need WebAuthn for a U2F...

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can do that with tpm-fido, see https://github.com/psanford/tpm-fido.

I've registered my TPM as security key in my Google account for example.